# How I can incorporate results of histogram stretching into georeferenced image?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, vrt

I have one channel 8 bit raster and when I open it in QGIS with histogram stretching "on the fly" it looks fine. How I can recalculate original raster accordingly changed histogram?

Answer (score 1):

You may use gdalinfo -hist to get histogram data of your image.

Then use the min & max & histogram data to compute the -scale parameter of a gdal_translate command that will stretch your histogram.